# how to Modify a child object from you state in the reducer with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, state

I have a state with multiple objects inside it. Right now I can modify all the elements from the first level, like the *step* property. But I want to know how to modify the elements from an object inside of my state.

**Initial state**

```
const initialState = {
  step : 1,
  user: {
    identification : {
      email:  '',
      username: '',
    },
    localization: {
      address:  '',
      country: '',
    }}
```

My payload is this object:

```
identification : {
    email: "some@html.com"
    username: "s032190" }
```

And my **rootReducer** is this:

```
function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload }  
    case CHANGE_STEP:
    return { ...state, step: action.payload }  
    case ADD_FIELD: 
      Object.keys(state.altaUsuario).forEach (cat => { 
          return { ...state.user, [cat] : action.payload}          
      })
    default:
    return state
  }
};
```

Is it fine to use a loop? I tried with the map or the foreach, nothing works.
I also tried to call property in the spread operator, something like this:

```
       return { ...state, altaUsuario[cat] : action.payload}
```

But it gives me a syntax error.

I can also modify the payload if is necessary.

Any idea??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

`return { ...state,user : {...state.user ,identification :action.payload }}`

Comment: almost, but it creates a new identification property in my user object. Now I have `user: { identification:{}, localization {}, identification{}}`

Comment: my bad, i mistake the object key. Thanks for you first good answer!

Answer (score 0):

if your action.payload is

```
{
  identification : {
  email: "some@html.com"
  username: "s032190"
   }
}
```

you have to override the identification property

```
return { ...state, user: { ...state.user, identification: action.payload.identification}
```